# OAuth issues with Google Docs API using Ruby (Rails 3.0.6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-docs, google-docs-api

We can't seem to create a new spreadsheet per the Google Docs API.

Our request merely hangs. We're on Rails 3.0.6.

Here's our code:

```
 msg = '<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
                 term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#document" />
  <atom:title>Company Perks</atom:title>
</atom:entry>'

oauth_base_string = 'POST&http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full&oauth_consumer_key=DOMAIN&oauth_nonce=1c4fbbe4387a685829d5938a3d97988c&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1227303732&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_requestor_id=ID'  

key = 'KEY'

oauth_signature = CGI.escape(Base64.encode64("#{OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', key, oauth_base_string)}"))

headers = { 
  'Content-Type' => 'application/atom+xml',
  'Authorization' => 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="DOMAIN",oauth_nonce"1c4fbbe4387a685829d5938a3d97988c",oauth_signature=' + oauth_signature + ',oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1227303732",oauth_version="1.0"'
}

uri = URI.parse 'http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full?xoauth_requestor_id=ID'
http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
http.use_ssl = true
resp, data = http.post(uri.request_uri, msg, headers)
```

Legend:

DOMAIN = OAuth consumer key
ID = the email address for whom we're trying to create a new spreadsheet
KEY = OAuth consumer secret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you're trying to write it manually?  If I were to guess, it'd be because your timestamp and nonce are hardcoded.  Also, IIRC Google uses Oauth 2.0 and supports 1.0a, so you'll likely need a request and access token.  From you example, I don't see that you are fetching it.

IMO, You're likely better off using a gem.

Omniauth is a fairly popular gem that does exactly what you need, and included the Google oauth strategy:
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Also, I've used this gem in the past, and it was useful for my project.
http://oauth.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Thanks, Cory. We hard coded this because all we need is 2-legged OAuth with Google Docs. We didn't want the extra baggage with a more general purpose gem. All we want to do is create a Google spreadsheet and write to it. Given our goals, do you think the extra weight of this gem is worth it? The API description for 2-legged authentication *seems* simple: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html#GoogleAppsOAuth

Comment: You're right, it isn't that difficult, although the gem is the quick and easy solution.  If you want to roll your own, I'd suggest having a look at Oauth requests are supposed to work: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#SigningOAuth  The basic auth flow is: 1) Obtain a request token, using OAuthGetRequestToken. 2) Authorize that request token, using OAuthAuthorizeToken. 3) Exchange the authorized request token for an access token, using OAuthGetAccessToken.  Also pay attention on how to generate a nonce and sign requests.